# for each + ajax request + delay

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I been desperately trying to get this working but I am no longer having hope and I would appreciate some help.
I will sum up the idea with a few lines and I'm sure you'll understand.

```
$(".el").each(function(){
    console.log("starting");
    // $.ajax GET request
    // console.log($.ajax response)
    // delay of 3 seconds
    console.log("finished, moving on.");
    // next
});
```

Assuming we have 3 elements, The result looks like this:

```
starting
finished, moving on.
starting
finished, moving on.
starting
finished, moving on.
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost/data.json".
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost/data.json".
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost/data.json".
```

I'm drowning with these ajax requests and I can't get anything work. I want it all to work asynchronically.

Comment: Are you doing anying in the `.done()`? Also are you using `async`?

Comment: Yes. Posted a solution below, thanks for trying to help me buddy.

Answer (score 2):

The usual pattern for this is to use asynchronous Ajax and then do manual iteration where you control when the next iteration starts:

```
function runIt() {
    var items = $(".el");
    var cntr = 0;

    function next() {
        if (cntr < items.length) {
            console.log("starting now..",cntr);
            // do something with items.eq(cntr)
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                async: true,
                url: "http://..."
            }).then(function() {
                console.log("finished, moving on.");
                ++cntr;
                setTimeout(next, 3000);
            });
        }
    }
    next();
}
```

Comment: This is really great, thanks for coming up with this method.

Answer (score 0):

I think with all my attempts, I just complicated things more than how they are.
I'm posting my solution in case some one else needs it.

```
$('.el').each(function(i){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("starting now..",i);
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            async: false,
            url: "http://"
        })
        .done(function( msg ) {
            console.log(msg);
        });

        console.log("ended. moving on to next element");
   },1000*i);
});
```

Comment: Did you also read WHY? :) I'm curious. On the other hand, which more options do I have?

Comment: Synchronous ajax locks up the browser during the ajax call (in this case during all your ajax calls) so the browser becomes unresponsive.  It's a generally horrible user experience and should pretty much never be used.  Also, can't be used with JSONP.

Comment: what are you suggesting? if there's a better way doing this, i'll be more than happy to hear!